# How to create a where query for Json in mysql with key having a white space in between the name

Tags: php, mysql, json

With json as

`{ "First Name": {"nickname" : "Abc"} }`

in json column 'name' of mysql database.

How do I extract such rows in mysql.

```
Select * from users where name."$.First Name.nickname" = "abc";
```

won't work. Any solution because I cannot change the json structure in database.

Comment: use like query <?php
$srch = '%"nickname" : "Abc"%';

$ss= 'Select * from users where column_name like '.$srch;

echo $ss;
?>

Comment: This [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) might help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
Select * from users where name."$.""First Name"".nickname" = "abc";
```

you need to double quote the key of JSON with a space.

Comment: `name->"$."`... *

Comment: Hello, We are on mysql version 5.5 and i have one column called USER_JSON in which datas are stored like this 

[{"userId":"LQ2138C","seenFlag":"0","seenDate":"0000\/00\/00 00:00:00"},{"userId":"LQ1839C","seenFlag":"0","seenDate":"0000\/00\/00 00:00:00"},{"userId":"LQ4396C","seenFlag":"0","seenDate":"0000\/00\/00 00:00:00"},{"userId":"LQ1462C","seenFlag":"0","seenDate":"0000\/00\/00 00:00:00"},{"userId":"LQ58522C","seenFlag":"0","seenDate":"0000\/00\/00 00:00:00"},{"userId":"LQ1687C","seenFlag":"0","seenDate":"0000\/00\/00 00:00:00"}]

Comment: You can also do: select * from users where name->'$."First Name".nickname' = "abc", which, I think, is clearer.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to convert json into array using [**`json_decode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$str='{ "First Name": {"nickname" : "Abc"} }';
$data=json_decode($str,TRUE);
```

The output of `json_decode` is

```
Array
(
    [First Name] => Array
        (
            [nickname] => Abc
        )

)
```

Extract `nickname` form array

```
 echo $name=$data['First Name']['nickname'];
```

And use in query as

```
Select * from users where name = '$name';
```

Comment: OP says _I cannot change the json structure in database._

Comment: `can't change the json structure in database` But it can fetch json form database and  extract its  value that's the easy way!!